# Should the tag [java-aot] be retired in favor of [jaotc] and [dex2oat]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

There are 11 questions tagged [jaotc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaotc) with the guidance:

> Jaotc is the Java Ahead-of-Time Compiler. It allows to generate native code from Java Byte Code.

There are 15 questions tagged [dex2oat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dex2oat) with the guidance:

> dex2oat is an on-device compiler suite that converts DEX files generated by the Android compiler into OAT files at install time, which are used by the new Android 5.0 runtime, ART, to enable higher performance by using Ahead of Time compilation instead of the older Just in Time (JIT) used in older versions of Android.

There are also four questions tagged [java-aot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-aot), which has no guidance:

- [Can you use jaotc (Java Ahead-of-Time Compiler) with jlink (module assembler/optimizer to create runtime images)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50221593/can-you-use-jaotc-java-ahead-of-time-compiler-with-jlink-module-assembler-opt)
- [JEP 295 AOT: Objects compiled multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46582922/jep-295-aot-objects-compiled-multiple-times)
- [Is Ahead-Of-Time compilation available in Java 9?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46579565/is-ahead-of-time-compilation-available-in-java-9)
- [Failed to create oat file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52294318/failed-to-create-oat-file)

The first three links to [the jaotc JEP](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/295) refer directly to [jaotc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jaotc) while the fourth seems to be about [dex2oat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dex2oat).  So can the [java-aot](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java-aot) tag be retired in favor of the other two tags?

Comment: Since there are only 4 questions I'm not actually sure this needs to be tagged [tag:burninate-request], since the cutoff for "ad hoc" tag removals is < 50 questions as per [What is the process for tag removal (burnination)?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/324070).